# MySQL Index for ORDER BY with Date Range in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Suppose you have a table with the following columns:

```
id
date
col1
```

I would like to be able to query this table with a specific id and date, and also order by another column. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = ? AND date > ? ORDER BY col1 DESC
```

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html) range documentation, an index will stop being used after it hits the `>` operator. But according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) order by documentation, an index can only be used to optimize the order by clause if it is ordering by the last column in the index. Is it possible to get an indexed lookup on every part of this query, or can you only get 2 of the 3? Can I do any better than `index (id, date)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plan A:  `INDEX(id, date)` -- works best if when it filters out a lot of rows, making the subsequent "filesort" not very costly.

Plan B:  `INDEX(col1)`, which may work best if very few rows are filtered by the WHERE clause.  This avoids the filesort, but is not necessarily faster than the other choices here.

Plan C:  `INDEX(id, date, col1)` -- This is a "covering" index *if* the query does not reference any other fields.  The potential advantage here is to look only at the index, and not have to touch the data.  If it applies, Plan C is better than Plan A.

You have not provided enough information to say which of these INDEXes will work best.  Suggest you add C and B, if "covering" applies; else add A and B.  The see which index the Optimizer picks.  (There is still a chance that the Optimizer will not pick 'right'.)

(These three indexes are what my [Index blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) recommends.)

Comment: Your algorighm is helpful. But I was under the impression from the [MySql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html) that even a "covering" index (C) would stop indexing at date because of the `>` condition in the where clause. Am I wrong about that? For my case, it doesn't really matter because I am selecting about 15+ columns. I simplified the problem for the question, but it's still good to know.

Comment: If you are selecting 15 columns, don't make a covering index.  Yes, the use of the index for filtering or ordering will stop because of the range condition.  It will (1) filter on the WHERE, then gather the rest of the stuff needed _only_ from the index, and sort it.  What is saved is not having to bounce between the index (one BTree) and the data (which is stored separately).